# Transformer not reading Special Character from Document Object

Tags: java, xml, xslt, encoding, utf-8

I am trying to read xml data from Document Object, and then using transformer to render the data inside the document object to pdf,using XSL,

My code is :

```
Document doc = toXML(arg1,arg2);
```

doc contains data like :
 
**İlkyönetmeliği**

  with in tags

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(xslFilePath);
transformer = factory.newTransformer(new StreamSource(inputStream));
transformer.setParameter("encoding", "UTF-8");
transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, "UTF-8");
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc.getDocumentElement()), res);
```

Special characters present in xml are not getting rendered accordingly and displaying like

**#lk yard#m**.

I have also set encoding to UTF-8 ,but still it is displaying  like above.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what causes your encoding problem because I cannot see how your document is read/constructed and how your transformation result `res` is set up. Try the following standalone example code which handles encoding with XSLT. Maybe you can even modify it gradually to use your actual data in order to see what goes wrong.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        String inputEncoding = "UTF-16";
        String xsltEncoding = "ASCII";
        String outputEncoding = "UTF-8";

        ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, inputEncoding);
        osw.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='" + inputEncoding + "'?>");
        osw.write("<root>İlkyönetmeliği</root>"); osw.close();
        byte[] inputBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.reset();

        osw = new OutputStreamWriter(bos, xsltEncoding);
        osw.write("<?xml version='1.0' encoding='" + xsltEncoding + "'?>");
        osw.write("<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl='http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform' version='1.0'>");
        osw.write("<xsl:template match='@*|node()'><xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select='@*|node()'/></xsl:copy></xsl:template>");
        osw.write("</xsl:stylesheet>"); osw.close();
        byte[] xsltBytes = bos.toByteArray();
        bos.reset();

        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document d = db.parse(new InputSource(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes), inputEncoding)));
        // if encoding declaration correct, use: Document d = db.parse(new InputSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(inputBytes)));
        System.out.println(XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath().evaluate("/root[1]", d));

        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer t = tf.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(xsltBytes), xsltEncoding)));
        // if encoding declaration correct, use: Transformer t = tf.newTransformer(new StreamSource(new ByteArrayInputStream(xsltBytes)));
        StreamResult sr = new StreamResult(new OutputStreamWriter(bos, outputEncoding));
        t.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.ENCODING, outputEncoding);
        t.transform(new DOMSource(d.getDocumentElement()), sr);
        byte[] outputBytes = bos.toByteArray();

        Scanner s = new Scanner(new InputStreamReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(outputBytes), outputEncoding));
        String output = s.useDelimiter("</>").next(); // read all
        s.close();

        System.out.println(output);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace(System.err);
    }
```

The example code applies the [XSLT identity template](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#copying) to a minimal input containing the non-ASCII characters.

I output the string to check if it has been parsed correctly in the document using XPath. You may want to check your (intermediate) document if you know how to locate it with XPath.

Note that, if present, the parser tries to pick up the encoding declared in the XML processing instruction (PI) by default when reading an XML file. It assumes that actual and declared encoding are the same. If they differ or the PI is missing, then you can enforce the actual encoding e.g. by using an `InputStreamReader` as in the code above.